# AngularJS Press Key Twice With Different Actions After Each Keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keypress, keydown

I need help pressing the Enter key twice with a different action occurring after each keypress in AngularJS, for example:

- Press Enter
- One action happens
- Press Enter again
- A different action happens

I can get the first action working, just not the second. Here's my code:

```
  $scope.enterPressed = 0;
  $document.bind('keydown', function (evt) {
    if (evt.which === 13) {
      alert('Enter pressed');
      if ($scope.enterPressed === 0) {
        $scope.enterPressed++;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Enter pressed once. $scope.enterPressed is " + $scope.enterPressed;
      } else if ($scope.enterPressed === 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Enter pressed twice. $scope.enterPressed i: " + $scope.enterPressed;
      }
    }
  });
```

[Here's a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/abdlbbHrwzh7PDe6Ewcm?p=preview).

How can I get the second action to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `e.preventDefault();` but `e` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 evt.preventDefault();
```